# Bugzilla install on Windows 7 with Apache & Mysql

Tags: apache, perl, bugzilla

Environment:
  Windows 7 Pro 64 bit.
  Apache 2.2.25
  ActivePerl 5.18.2 Build 1802 (64 bit)
  Bugzilla 4.4.5 (extracted)

Okay, I have followed step-by-step instructions as indicated here: https://wiki.mozilla.org/Bugzilla:Win32Install

There's 1 major issue that I've researched all day and cannot find a solution.  It's the "ppm install DBD-mysql" issue.  There is no "DBD-mysql".  When I use the ppm gui, there's a DBD-mysqlpp , but that's not what's needed.

When I run in a command window:  C:\bugzilla\checksetup.pl , I get the only error:
    Checking for DBD-mysql (v4.001) not found

```
For MySQL, Bugzilla requires that perl's DBD::mysql 4.001 or later be
installed. To install this module, run the following command (as Administrator):

ppm install DBD-mysql
```

Well, I found DBD-mysql 4.028 here:  http://search.cpan.org/~capttofu/DBD-mysql-4.028

However, trying to get the perl ppm (perl package manager) gui to see it, but even pointing the link in the gui preferences it still wouldn't see it to download and install it.  This sucks.

So, I manually downloaded it and saw some crap "makefile.pl" file.  Look, I use WINDOWS not LINUX, so naturally I rolled my eyes but it quickly became clear that I *HAD* to do this.  Well, after about an hour of screwing around I was finally able to make a mysql_config.pl file.  Oh wow, great.... now what!?  What do I do next with this??

Not only is this part aggravating, but now I need mod_perl in my Apache.  Okay, so I look in my .conf file where I can uncomment:

```
#LoadModule perl_module modules/mod_perl.so
```

Guess what... it's not there.  (facepalm)

So I researched and downloaded mod_perl 2.0.8 from: http://perl.apache.org/download/index.html

Heh, ... guess what... another damn "makefile" file!!  Let me tell you, this is as bad as being a MAC user in the late 90's and trying to find a program to be compatible.

So, my 2 main questions are these:

1. How do I get DBD-mysql properly installed
2. How do I get the mod_perl properly installed

I have been working 12 hours non-stop trying to get Bugzilla installed.  At this point, I'm so frustrated beyond believe I'm ready to scrap this and install flyspray or some other php/mysql bug tracking system.

Comment: What is the state of play at present? You've downloaded the files--have you run `perl Makefile.PL`, `make`, `make test`, and `make install` to actually install the stuff you've downloaded?

Comment: I performed the 'perl Makefile.PL', but that's all. I can just chalk the whole thing up to not knowing perl. For the record, I scrapped Bugzilla for Flyspray. I'm a PHP/MySQL guy, and Flyspray was simple to install & configure. Bugzilla is NOT meant for a windows environment, period. The documentation Bugzilla has for Windows installations is outdated and does not work with the current versions of Perl. I can deal with that, but I would love to use it because I'm a fan of Mozilla products and Bugzilla seems to have an awesome support community. Thanks, 'i alarmed alien', for replying.

Comment: You need to run `make` and `make install` to install the things that you downloaded -- did you read the installation instructions? Both DBD::mysql and mod_perl have installation instructions for windows. If you've already spent 12+ hours on it, it's not going to hurt to spend a little longer reading and following the installation instructions.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference in case anyone stumbles upon this item:

Most Perl modules have installation instructions, either in their .pod documentation or in a README or INSTALL file.

Most Perl modules follow a similar installation mechanism: create a makefile; run `make`; `make test` (which runs a set of tests, unsurprisingly), and then install the module. From the commandline, this looks like the following:

```
$ perl Makefile.PL
$ make
$ make test
$ make install
```

Both [`mod_perl`](https://metacpan.org/release/mod_perl) and [`DBD::mysql`](https://metacpan.org/release/DBD-mysql) have platform-specific installation information in the release notes.

Answer (score 0):

`DBD-mysql` is a package that you can find in ActiveState Package Repository. That means that it should be installed at the time you installed ActivePerl, making your question really strange. I know it because I just did it yesterday, and everything worked just fine.

A possible solution for this issue is:

1. Open the command line in Windows;
2. Type `ppm`, press enter and wait. A GUI for the Perl Package Manager will be displayed;
3. Search for DBD-mysql. If you find it, schedule it for installation by right-clicking it and clicking on **Install DBD-mysql 4.022**;

Although, you probably won't find it. If you don't, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and, in the dialog that appears, select the Repositories tab. Add a new repository:

- Name: ActiveState-Package-Repository
- Location: http://ppm4.activestate.com/MSWin32-x64/5.16/1604/package.xml

It will update the list of packages. Repeat steps 1 to 3.

If you prefer doing it by the command line, these are the instructions:

```
ppm repo add ActiveState-Package-Repository http://ppm4.activestate.com/MSWin32-x64/5.16/1604/package.xml
ppm install DBD-mysql
```